# Automorphisms of $\mathbb{A}^{n}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, affine-geometry, jacobian, affine-varieties

Let $\varphi: \mathbf{A}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbf{A}^{n}$ be a morphism of $\mathbf{A}^{n}$ to $\mathbf{A}^{n}$ given by $n$ polynomials $f_{1}, \ldots, f_{n}$ of $n$ variables $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n} .$ Let $J=\operatorname{det}\left|\partial f_{i} / \partial x_{j}\right|$ be the Jacobian polynomial of $\varphi .$

> show that If $\varphi$ is an isomorphism (in which case we call $\varphi$ an automorphism of $\mathbf{A}^{n}$ ) show that $J$ is a nonzero constant polynomial.

solution :

If $\varphi \in \operatorname{Aut}\left(\mathbb{A}^{n}\right),$ then each $f_{i} \notin k,$ since then $\varphi$ is not surjective. Therefore each $f_{i}$ is a linear non-constant polynomial, so $J \in k^{\times}$

> why  $f_{i} \notin k$ ? why each $f_{i}$ is a linear non-constant polynomial ? also why $J \in k^{\times}$ ?

Comment: Where did you get this solution?  It is not correct that each $f_i$ must be linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $J\in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$
- $J$ doesn't vanish on $\overline{k}^n$
- Thus $J$ is constant, it is in $k^\times$

For $n=2$ try with $\varphi(x_1,x_2)=(x_1+x_2^2,x_2)$ to see that $Aut(\Bbb{A}^n)$ is much more complicated than $Aut(\Bbb{P}^n)$ where we get "it must be linear".

The Jacobian conjecture is the converse: if $J\in k^\times$ then does $\varphi$ have to be an automorphism?

Comment: Because every element of jacobian matrix is polynomial then : $J\in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.why $J$ doesn't vanish on $\overline{k}^n$ ? 
($\overline{k}$ is algebraic closure of $k$? ) I can't understand why $j$ is constant ?

Comment: If $J=0$ then $ det(...) =0$   and if $det=0$ then $\varphi$ is not automprphism  ?  is this true ? Why ?

Comment: Because the matrix of polynomials $M_{ij}=\partial_j f_i$  has an inverse at each point, given by $\varphi^{-1}$. Then a non-constant polynomial always has some zero in the algebraic closure.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Try using the inverse polynomial map and the chain rule. What are the invertible  elements of a polynomial ring?

Comment: What is inverse polynomial map ?

Comment: @1200785626 You're saying that your map is an isomorphism, so there must exist another polynomial map $\psi$ such that $\psi\varphi$ and $\varphi\psi$ are the identity. Try to figure out, using the chain rule, what this entails about their Jacobian matrices.